# jquery hover and setTimeout / clearTimeOut

Tags: jquery, hover, settimeout

I'm currently trying to do a menu with submenu.
Here is what i want to do.

On hover a link (#mylink) i want to display a div (lets call it "#submenu") right under it.
On mouse leave this link a want to execute a function after 5 second.

In this interval of 5 seconds, if i hover my div (#submenu) i want to clearTimeout.
So this div won't desapear after 5 seconds.

Here is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#mylink").hover(
        function ()
        {
            $('#submenu').show();
        },
        function()
        {
            var timer = setTimeout(function(){$('#submenu').hide();}, 5000);
        }
    );

    $("#submenu").hover(
        function ()
        {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        },
        function()
        {
            $('#submenu').show();
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SLaks has the right answer, but to elaborate on it, you would put `var timer` outside the function handler. Note that this example doesn't make `timer` a global variable - it just widens its scope so all handlers can use it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var timer;
    $("#mylink").hover(
        function(){
            $('#submenu').show();
        }, function(){
            timer = setTimeout(function(){$('#submenu').hide();}, 5000);
        }
    );

    $("#submenu").hover(
        function(){
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }, function(){
            $('#submenu').show();
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`var timer` is a local variable.
It doesn't exist outside that handler.

You need to make it a global variable.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I would do it

```
var timer
$("#mylink").mouseenter(function(){clearTimeout(timer);$('#submenu').show()})
$("#mylink").mouseout(function(){timer = setTimeout(function(){$('#submenu').hide();}, 1000);})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you put #submenu inside of #mylink you won't need a second event handler for #submenu and you would have something like this:

```
var timer;
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#mylink').hover(function()
    {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $('#submenu').show();
    },function()
    {
        timer = setTimeout(function(){$('#submenu').hide();},5000);
    });
}
```

By the way, you don't need jQuery for this. In plain js won't be so long to code.