# List show hide with jquery

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I have this list:

```
<ol id="followUs">
    <li>Follow us</li>
    <li class="blog"><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li class="linkedIn"><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li class="twitter"><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li class="facebook"><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li class="smartPhone"><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li id="shareMore">More
        <ul id="socialMore" style="display: none;">
            <li id="youtube"><a href="#">Youtube</a></li>
            <li id="flickr"><a href="#">FlickR</a></li>
            <li id="slideshare"><a href="#">SlideShare</a></li>
            <li id="newsletter"><a href="#">Newsletter</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ol>
```

And the following jQuery:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("li#shareMore").mouseenter(function() {
        jQuery('ul#socialMore').css("display","block");
        jQuery('span.popin_header_button').css("display","none");
    });

    jQuery("li#shareMore").mouseleave(function() {
        setTimeout( function(){
            jQuery('ul#socialMore').css("display","none");  
            jQuery('span.popin_header_button').css("display","block");
        },1000);
    });
})
</script>
```

The second list #socialMore is hidden on page load, and I want to show it on mouseover, and this to stay there as I hover around the lists of #socialMore. Problem is, the list is appearing and disappearing when I'm still hovering the #socialMore list (unless the second list overlaps the first one, which I don't want).

Secondly, I want staffs around to be positioned below the list, which is not happenning and hence I need to hide those.

For the CSS, the first list #followUs is horizontal and the second list #shareMore is vertical.

Anyone can suggest a solution here. Not getting what's getting wrong.

Thanks for passing by.

**EDIT on 15th Oct**

I changed the jQuery to:

```
jQuery("li#shareMore").hover(function() {
    jQuery('li#shareMore>ul').show();
},function(){
        setTimeout( function(){
            jQuery('li#shareMore>ul').hide();   
        },2000);
    }
);
```

It works, but unstable. At times, it works perfectly, and at times, the ul just goes away even I am still hovering the first `<li id="shareMore">More`

**EDIT II: on 15th Oct**

Pushing it further, I found that it's not really unstable. The logic is, on page refresh, if I hover `li#shareMore` without going to the `>ul` list, it works as expected. The first time when I hover on the `>ul` list, it works as expected as well. However, once I hover out from the `>ul` list, from the following times the `>ul` list disappears within the setTimeOut time, 2 seconds in this case.

However, if I set setTimeOut limit to 0, everything works as expected. This is the observation so far, unless I'm missing something. Strange world !

Thanks for any hints > strange situation.

**EDIT**

It seems solved finally, using cleartimeout: [jquery hover and setTimeout / clearTimeOut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299531/jquery-hover-and-settimeout-cleartimeout)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `show()` and `hide()` functions of jquery for this.Like

```
 $('ul#socialMore').show();
 $('span.popin_header_button').hide();
```

Comment: Thanks Abu, but unfortunately this is not really relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("li#shareMore").mouseenter(function() {
       $('ul#socialMore').show();
    });

    jQuery("li#shareMore").mouseleave(function() {
       $('ul#socialMore').hide();
    });
})
```

see: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/liorlolo/G4jpF/2/)

Comment: This is not working for me, probably because I have put the second list below the first list using a css, and when I leave the first list's horizon and enters that of the second list, it's considered mouseleaved.

Answer (score 0):

can you try with below code

```
jQuery("li#shareMore").on("mouseout", 'ul#socialMore li', function() {
    setTimeout( function(){
        jQuery('ul#socialMore').css("display","none");  
        jQuery('span.popin_header_button').css("display","block");
    },1000);
});
```

start using "on" event of jquery.

Comment: Thanks usergigantic, but not working. Closest is what i'm getting is ` `jQuery("li#shareMore").mouseenter(function() {
        jQuery('ul#socialMore').show();
    });
 jQuery("ul#socialMore").mouseenter(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
    jQuery("ul#socialMore").mouseleave(function() {
  setTimeout( function(){
   jQuery('ul#socialMore').hide(); 
  },1000);
    });`
` but here, I am unable to get rid of the second list if I just hover the "more" link and out.