# Unique Mix of hoverIntent and timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, hoverintent

I have this situation where if hovering over a `#main-nav li` item it will show the `subnav`. But I need a delay to allow user to reach it (`subnav`). I've tried solutions like **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299531/jquery-hover-and-settimeout-cleartimeout)** but if I hover on another item, it doesn't hide the previous hovered item until delay is over. Then I tried adding if statements within handlerOut to determine if hovering over *another* nav item or mouseOut `#main-nav` section allowing the timer to run (but doesn't run since within handlerOut).

Here's the code below and **[here it is on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mikemiketm09/rujwd/2/).**

```
var $mainlist = $('#main-nav li');
var $subnav = $('#main-nav li ul');

$(function () {

    $mainlist.hoverIntent(

    function () {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    },

    function () {
        if ($('#main-nav li').hover() && $('#main-nav li').not($(this))) {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        } else if ($('#main-nav').add($subnav).mouseleave()) {
            timer = setTimeout(function () {
                $('#main-nav').find('li.active').removeClass('active');
            }, 1000);
        }
    });

    $subnav.hover(

    function () {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    },

    function () {
        //
    });
});
```

Please disregard how the `sub-nav` is positioned as it relates to the site styling.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few issues with your code:

First, the selectors:

If you want the immediate children, use `>`:

```
var $mainlist = $('#main-nav > li');
```

You also forgot the `#` in the second selector.

From there, it was pretty straight-forward, assuming I got your scenario correctly:

- When entering a main list item, I remove the `active` class from the
  previously selected item, if any.
- When leaving the such element, create a timeout that allows you to enter the sub-menu.
- When entering the sub-menu, clear the timeout to leave the sub-menu visible.
- When leaving the sub-menu, deactivate it.

A working version can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rujwd/3/).

Note that I colorized the sub-menu to make it clear when you're entering or leaving it.

Comment: Thanks for the catch! This is the perfect fix and I fined tuned it further. Thank you.